# How to use volley in Android libraries

Tags: android, android-volley, android-library

I have a project in which am using volley library.
I have a `MyApplication` class :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Now to use that in my project, am adding the class name in my `Manifest` file.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        >
```

Everything is working fine.

Coming to main question,am also making a library in which I need to use volley.
In my library, I again created a `MyApplication` class and in the manifest I added the application name. I also added the Internet permission in the manifest.

But when am calling the function in my it's giving me null reference error.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
```

**My questions:**

a) We can use volley's in our libraries. right?

b) If yes, why it's showing me error? If NO, then how do I interact with the server?

Since I plan to make a maven repo, I can't do changes in main project file.

I tried changing the application name in project's Manifest to librarie's `MyApplication` class. In that case it was able to connect to the server.

But what if user has already changed the application name for their custom class, how do I achieve my goal in that case?

I also tried singleton class, it's also showing me same error.

Thanks

Comment: Are libraries supposed to use an `Application` class? You don't need it to use Volley, and I am sure you can use Volley in a library.

Comment: Are you calling getRequestQueue before the add methods? beacuse is there where you create the instance of RequestQueue.

Comment: @cricket_007, so do you mean to say that a project can have sorta only one application class? The libraries can't have their own application class?

Comment: @Pablo, no. am not calling the getRequestQueue before the add method.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop making singletons that extend application. Its bad practice. Do something like:

```
public class MySingleton{
        private static MySingleton mInstance;
        private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
        private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        private static Context mCtx;

        public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
            if(mInstance == null) mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
            return mInstance;
        }

        private MySingleton(Context context) {
            mCtx = context;
            mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
        }

        public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
            if (mRequestQueue == null) {
                mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
            }
            return mRequestQueue;
        }

        public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
            req.setTag(Config.TAG);
            getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }

        public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
            req.setTag(tag);
            getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }

        public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
            return mImageLoader;
        }

        public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag){
            if(mRequestQueue != null){
                mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
            }
        }

        public static boolean canConnect(Context context){
            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(info != null && info.isConnected()) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And call it like `MySingleton.getInstance(context)`....
E.g. `MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);`
You also won't need to declare anything in manifest like this.

Comment: I tried making singleton class too. But in this case too am getting nullpointer exception.

Comment: Just to try your code, I ran it. It gives me same error ` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)
            at com.iamanubhaw.xyz.MySingleton.getRequestQueue(MySingleton.java:50)` .
This line : `mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());`

Comment: Wherever you are getting your context from, It was created before any context actually exist. Are you using it in a broadacast receiver or service, post a sample use case or your exact use case so i may be of further help. Cause i have used that code in voluminous number of apps without faliure

Comment: I am not using any service or broadcast receiver. I have a class in my library name xyz which extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener

Now in my main project am initializing it as abc a=new abc();
a.initialize();

Inside initialize i have a function which calls server. That's it.

Comment: Would you be willing to explain why singletons that extend application is a bad practice? The official documentation hooks up Volley in that way

Comment: There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton.

Comment: The entire idea of using a singleton in most cases is to create something that may be used across many application context. So why extend an application in the first instance?

Answer (score 0):

`RequestQueue` should be an application singleton so you needn't 'lock' it in your library. Rather define some interface which future applications must provide in order to start using your library. Kind of

```
interface RequestQueueProvider {
   RequestQueue getRequestQueue();
}
```

So that application must pass some inplementation to your library initialization code, some class constructors or whatever. Apllication can also use this `RequestQueue` to make it's own requests.

Comment: Your `MyApplication` class implements aforementioned interface as well as Richard McFriend's `MySingleton` does. Your library may for example have `GreateQuestion` class  which constructor requiers a parameter of type `RequestQueueProvider` So you can have `GreateQuestion mGQ = new GreateQuestion(this); ` in your class. Or `GreateQuestion mGQ = new GreateQuestion(MySingleton.getInstace(this));` within `onCreate` of the activity using  Richard McFriend's example.